# Display data in the web application with Event-Driven Microservice Architecture

Tags: microservices, event-driven-design

I am new to event-driven microservices and am interested in what is the best way to display data in a web application in such an architecture.
Let say I have 2 microservices: Orders and Products with separated databases per service, and nservicebus to send events.
What I can display the list of orders in the web app? Should I add one more database for the Web app and some SubscriberService that subscribes to events and stores replicas of data when orders or products were changed? Or it is better to add web api in microservices in order to receive data in the Web app? I also know there is an option to use ETL to populate replicas to WebAppDatabase

Comment: If you duplicate data you should somehow verify if your data is consistent between services - seems problematic to me. On the other hand I think that communicating via web api goes against EDA. Maybe requesting to display data should be an event? I don't know...